# Big Max Shed Foundation

Tags: concrete, gravel, foundation

I have a 7 x 7 big max resin shed, resin floor.

I'm putting in the corner of my yard for about year until we do some serious landscaping then it will be moved to a new location.

What should I use for foundation?

I was thinking 2-3 inches of gravel then 0.5 inch piece of treated ply wood.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 8):

I always liked 2' x 2' concrete paving slabs as they are reusable.  A piece of plywood, even on top of gravel will be worse for wear after any really wet period. They are a bit tricky to get perfectly level unless you compact the gravel underneath first.

Paving slabs will drain water but any leakage inside will sit on plywood or be absorbed